# android - How to shift EditText to top when focused?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio-2.2

I have a view which contains an ImageView on top and an EditText with a Button below.
How can I shift ImageView out of the screen, when keyboard appears, to allow show EditText and the Button?

This is my layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="com.archimedia.appToYours.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">


            <!-- this is what I want to shift up out of the screen -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/upToYoursImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:contentDescription=""
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/_title"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/code"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/targa"
                android:ems="15"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:hint="Some text..."
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:maxLength="15"
                android:paddingLeft="60dp"
                android:textColor="#222"
                android:textColorHint="#222"
                android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:textColorSecondary="#222"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                tools:ignore="InefficientWeight">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/send_button"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Go!"
                   android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display3"
                    android:textSize="38sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
            </RelativeLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar requirement. The way I solved it was to listen to **LayoutChanged** events on the root view. Once I saw that the view got smaller in height, I assumed that the keyboard opened and reacted accordingly.
Here's a sample of that approach. Hope it helps:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.activity_main).addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
            if (bottom < oldBottom) {
                // View got smaller in height
                // In this case this means that the keyboard was opened
                findViewById(R.id.upToYoursImageView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // View got larger in height
                findViewById(R.id.upToYoursImageView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

Comment: It just hide the ImageView when keyboard appaers, but the EditTextView doesn't come up, and the Button still doesn't is shown

Comment: You could also add it to a scrollview, and scroll to bottom once the keyboard is opened.
-> scroll.post(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
           scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);              
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

i think you can add a ScrollView 
try this code and i hope it helps

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="com.archimedia.appToYours.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">


            <!-- this is what I want to shift up out of the screen -->
            <ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/upToYoursImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:contentDescription=""
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/_title"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/code"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/targa"
                android:ems="15"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:hint="Some text..."
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:maxLength="15"
                android:paddingLeft="60dp"
                android:textColor="#222"
                android:textColorHint="#222"
                android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:textColorSecondary="#222"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
                android:textSize="40sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry" />
            </ScrollView>
            
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                tools:ignore="InefficientWeight">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/send_button"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Go!"
                   android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display3"
                    android:textSize="38sp"
                    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
            </RelativeLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: im sorry i did a mistake with 
layout_width="match_parent" 
try remove it and give it a try 
at least i tried with it